# Restricting rijndaelmanaged algorithm key size?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using rijndaelmanaged algoritham for password encryption

Is there a way to restrict the size of the encrypted text key?

eg:1, ABC - Encrypted key size 10

```
  2, ABCDHGF - Encrypted key size 10
```

Means Fixed size !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not need to have password back from encrypted data, you can use hash algorithms. First compute the hash value for the password and then encrypt this hash value. Since hash values have fixed length your encrypted data will have a fixed length. When you need to check a password, decrypt the encrypted value and recalculate hash value from entered password then check if they match.

For example on a sign up page

```
var encryptedPwd = Encrypt(ComputeHash(txtPassword.Text));
Save(txtUsername.Text, encryptedPwd);
```

And on a login page

```
var encryptedPwd = SelectPwd(txtUsername.Text);
var pwdHash1 = Decrypt(encryptedPwd);
var pwdHash2 = ComputeHash(txtPassword.Text);

if (AreEqual(pwdHash1, pwdHash2))
   // Login OK!
else
   // Login fail
```

Another option could be making a custom padding. Say your passwords will have max length of 16 characters. Then you can pad every password to 16 chars with some fixed char. Then encrypt this padded password. It would be easier for validation but using hash is a bit more secure.

Sign up

```
var encryptedPwd = Encrypt(txtPassword.Text.PadRight(16, 'X'));
Save(txtUsername.Text, encryptedPwd);
```

Login

```
var encryptedPwd = SelectPwd(txtUsername.Text);
var pwd1 = Decrypt(encryptedPwd);
var pwd2 = txtPassword.Text.PadRight(16, 'X');

if (AreEqual(pwd1, pwd2))
   // Login OK!
else
   // Login fail
```

Comment: Means its not possibile in Rijndael algoritham?

Comment: Yes. As your plain data size changes your encrypted data size will change too.

Comment: Thanks for your help, But i have already used Rijndael algoritham and already have many encrypted password in my Db. So is not possible to change to another algoritham

Comment: I think there have been a misunderstanding. None of these solutions requires change of encryption algorithm, both still use Rijndael. If you already have encrypted passwords in your db you can fetch and decrypt them and then re-insert after encrypting with one of these solutions.

Comment: Sorry i didnt get you, can u explain me some more .Currently i am using the following code        public static string Encrypt("Welcome",  "LED2080p")
    {
        var algorithm = GetAlgorithm(encryptionPassword);
        byte[] encryptedBytes;
        using (ICryptoTransform encryptor = algorithm.CreateEncryptor(algorithm.Key, algorithm.IV))
        {
            byte[] bytesToEncrypt = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(textToEncrypt);
            encryptedBytes = InMemoryCrypt(bytesToEncrypt, encryptor);
        } return Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedBytes);
    }

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a simple hash, it's suggested to use a password-strengthening algorithm, like the one specified in Rfc2898

```
string password = "P@$$w0rd";
byte[] salt = new byte[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 }; // this is fixed... It would be better you used something different for each user

// You can raise 1000 to greater numbers... more cycles = more security. Try
// balancing speed with security.
Rfc2898DeriveBytes pwdGen = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt, 1000);

// generate key and iv
byte[] key = pwdGen.GetBytes(16);
byte[] iv = pwdGen.GetBytes(16);


byte[] encrypted;

{
    RijndaelManaged rijndaelCipher = new RijndaelManaged();
    rijndaelCipher.Key = key;
    rijndaelCipher.IV = iv;

    // Or your data
    byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("hello world");
    var encryptor = rijndaelCipher.CreateEncryptor();

    encrypted = encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(data, 0, data.Length);
}

{
    RijndaelManaged rijndaelCipher = new RijndaelManaged();
    rijndaelCipher.Key = key;
    rijndaelCipher.IV = iv;

    var decryptor = rijndaelCipher.CreateDecryptor();

    byte[] decrypted = decryptor.TransformFinalBlock(encrypted, 0, encrypted.Length);

    // this if you are encrypting text, otherwise decrypted is already your data
    string text = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decrypted);
}
```